# "Is there a way to set any object as dynamic as according devices resolution in flutter?"

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am creating one design with one center circle container and 5 circle container on edge of the center circle, But when the same code run in different devices they change it's position also there are image link in the last which show the design which i created.

"This is the design code which i created."

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/circle/firstCircle.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/circle/secondCircle.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/circle/thirdCircle.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/circle/fourthCircle.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/circle/fifthCircle.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(){
   runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()));
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  MyAppState createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    print('Hieght is $height and width is $width');
    return new Container(
      child: Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new Center(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(130.0),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.orange,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          ),
          //First Circle
            new Positioned(
              //alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, -0.9),
//                top: height/25,
//                left: width/2 - 80,
              //alignment: Alignment(0,-1.5),
              child: new GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  //margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.0,right: 1.0),
                  // alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
                  width: width/9,
                  height: width/9,
                  //child: Image.asset('assets/one.png'),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/one.png'),),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstCircle(),)),
              ),
              top: 30,
              right: 1.0,
              left: 1.0,
            ),
            //Second Circle
            new Positioned(
              //alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.57, -0.35),
              child: new GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width/9,
                  height: width/9,
//                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: width/2),
                  //child: Image.asset('assets/two.png'),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/two.png'),),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondCircle(),)),
              ),
              top: height/3,
              right: rightSize(),
              left: 1.0,
            ),
            //Third Circle
            new Positioned(
              //alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.57, -0.35),
              child: new GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width/9,
                  height: width/9,
//                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width/2),
                  //child: Image.asset('assets/three.png'),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/three.png'),),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdCircle(),)),
              ),
              top: height/3,
              left: leftSize(),
              right: 1.0,
            ),
            //Fourth Circle
            new Positioned(
//              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.35, 0.75),
              child: new GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width/9,
                  height: width/9,
                  //child: Image.asset('assets/four.png'),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/four.png'),),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FourthCircle(),)),
              ),
              bottom: bottomSize(),
              right: 1.0,
              left: 1.0 - width/4,
            ),
            //Fifth Circle
            new Positioned(
//              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.35, 0.75),
              child: new GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width/9,
                  height: width/9 ,
                  //child: Image.asset('assets/five.png'),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/five.png'),),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FifthCircle(),)),
              ),
              bottom: bottomSize(),
              right: 1.0 - width/4,
              left: 1.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }

  rightSize(){
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double rightSize;
    if(width > 1300){
      rightSize = width/2 + 100;
    }
    else if(width >= 1280) {
      rightSize = width/2 - 80;
    }
    else if(width == 1024){
      if(height == 552){
        rightSize = width/3;
      }
      else{
        //rightSize = width/2;
        rightSize = width/2;
      }
    }
    else if(width >= 960)
    {
      rightSize = width/2.8;
    }
    return rightSize;
  }
  leftSize(){
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double leftSize;
    if(width > 1300){
      leftSize = width/2 + 100;
    }
    else if(width >= 1280){
      leftSize = width/2 - 80;
    }
    else if(width >= 1024){
      if(height >= 552){
        leftSize = width/3;
      }
      else{
        leftSize = width/2;
      }
    }
    else if(width >= 960){
      leftSize = width/2.8;
    }
    return leftSize;
  }
  bottomSize(){
    double bottomSize;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    if(height >= 552){
      bottomSize = height/7;
    }
    else{
      bottomSize = height/10;
    }
    return bottomSize;
  }
}
```

[image]

"I am expecting universal design work on every possible devices."

Answer (score 0):

When i am trying create above design i thought i give them specific size and it's position but that not work for all devices so i used MediaQuery to fix all size and position. 
I hope this help others.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app2/circles/firstCircle.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app2/circles/secondCircle.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app2/circles/thirdCircle.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: width,
                height: height,
                child: Image.asset('assets/main_circle.png',fit: BoxFit.contain,),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: height - 100,
                width: width - 100,
                //color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height/1.6),
                          child: Container(
                            height: height/9,
                            width: width/9,
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              //color: Colors.blue,
                              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/one.png')),
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstCircle(),)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: height/1.7, bottom: width/7.5),
                          child: Container(
                            height: height/9,
                            width: width/9,
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              //color: Colors.blue,
                              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/two.png')),
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondCircle(),)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: height/1.9,bottom: width/7.5),
                          child: Container(
                            height: height/9,
                            width: width/9,
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              //color: Colors.blue,
                              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/three.png')),
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdCircle(),)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: height/2.20,right: height/2.8),
                          child: Container(
                            height: height/9,
                            width: width/9,
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              //color: Colors.blue,
                              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/four.png')),
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () => launch('https://www.google.co.in'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: height/2.20,left: height/3.5),
                          child: Container(
                            height: height/9,
                            width: width/9,
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              //color: Colors.blue,
                              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/five.png')),
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () => launch('https://youtu.be/sPW7nDBqt8w'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```